# XSD for name value enum

Tags: java, enums, xsd, jaxb, schema

I want to define an XSD to have the enums as define in java like

```
YES(Y), NO(N)
```

But I coundn't find a way to do that

How ever I saw [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html) , in example 2, they defined what I need  but I coundn't find any example for this

```
     //Example: code fragment
 @XmlType
 @XmlEnum(Integer.class)
 public enum Coin { 
     @XmlEnumValue("1") PENNY(1),
     @XmlEnumValue("5") NICKEL(5),
     @XmlEnumValue("10") DIME(10),
     @XmlEnumValue("25") QUARTER(25) }

 <!-- Example: XML Schema fragment -->
 <xs:simpleType name="Coin">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
     <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="25"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```